# JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have wriiten my connection pooling by extending connection and driver class. It is working fine but the problem is I want to now impose a upper limit and if te upper limit is reached then I want to store the request in the queue and return when any connections are free. How can I do this.
Thanks in advance for replys

Comment: Is there a need for writing your own connection pool?

Comment: Yes We need our own pool

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad, bad design.

Your pool should not require you to extend anything.  It should not be concerned with requests, either.  Just check connections in and out.  Have another component manage a queue of requests and collaborate with your pool to get connections.

Connection pools have been done.  The easiest one to maintain is the one that's written by someone else.

Comment: @siree - duffymo is right. Take a look at Apache's commons-dbcp if you need a connection pool for your database.

Comment: If I need to create our own connection pool. How can I do that. Actually we need a standalone java program that helps in managing connections

Comment: @siree: why do you need a connection pool for a standalone (one concurrent user) program? Or is it a server-side application?

Comment: it is not a server side apllication. We have a scheduler(quartz scheduler) a stand alone java program that updates few database tables. For managing those connections I need a connection pool